# What are the (dis)advantages of having tribesmen in your empire?

Tags: imperator-rome

As far as I can tell there are 4 types of pops in Imperator Rome:

1. Citizens
2. Freemen
3. Slaves
4. Tribesmen

Sometimes Tribesmen ask to settle/leave your empire, and it is possible to civilize them and turn them into slaves or freemen. What are the dis- and/or advantages of having tribesmen in your empire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Population](https://imperator.paradoxwikis.com/Population)

Each pop generates slightly differnet things:

> - Citizens - They provide research and commerce income.
> - Freemen - They provide manpower.
> - Tribesmen - These provide a tiny amount of manpower and tax income.
> - Slaves - These provide tax income.

You can civilize via promotion.

> Promoting a slave or tribesmen to freemen costs 10 oratory power,
>   promoting a freemen to citizen costs 10 oratory power.

The key issue with tribesmen is happiness.

> Happiness impacts two things on the pop, first of all, a pops
>   happiness directly affects how productive they are. Secondly, low
>   happiness increases unrest in a city.

You are probably going to increase the level of civilisation of your nation over time, which will make your tribesmen less happy.

> Civilization Value is a rating that exists in all locations on the
>   map, and it represents the level of infrastructure and urbanisation in
>   that location. This is a big factor for pop happiness. Tribesmen will
>   be happier in cities with low Civilization value whereas more
>   stratified pop types such as Freemen and especially Citizens prefer
>   locations with high Civilization value.

Comment: As a comment, your research speed depends on the ratio of produces research points to total population. So by having lots of tribesmen in high-civilized nation you increase the required amount of research points for maintaining the same research speed. At the same time, those tribesmen start to produce less and less compared to other pop types. That's why you want to convert them to more efficient pop types via government policy or spending points